# ActiveSupport::MessageVerifier::InvalidSignature (ActiveSupport::MessageVerifier::InvalidSignature):

Tags: ruby-on-rails, form-data

I am using formData to send form fields that includes an Image to my rails API. so far it works well but whenever I send that formData that doesn't include an Image I get this error `ActiveSupport::MessageVerifier::InvalidSignature (ActiveSupport::MessageVerifier::InvalidSignature):` in my rails app. My controller looks like this

```
  def create
    @transaction = @current_user.wallet.transactions.new(transaction_params)

    if @transaction.save
      render json: @transaction, status: :created
    else
      render json: @transaction.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity
    end
  end

 def transaction_params
      params.require(:transaction).permit(:amount, :coin_type, :status, :address, :transaction_type, :receipt )
    end
```

the model looks like this

```
class Transaction < ApplicationRecord
  has_one_attached :receipt
  belongs_to :wallet
  enum :coin_type, {BITCOIN: 0, ETHERUM: 1, "USD THETHER" => 2}
  enum :status, {pending: 0, completed: 1}
  enum :transaction_type, {deposit: 0, withdraw: 1}


  before_create :valid_transaction?
  

  def valid_transaction?
    raise ActiveRecord::RecordNotSaved, "You have limited funds in your wallet"  unless amount < wallet.wallet_balance || transaction_type == "deposit"
    true    
  end

  def receipt_url
    Rails.application.routes.url_helpers.url_for(receipt) if receipt.attached?
    
  end

end
```

this image is stored in the receipt params